# How to combine 4 Tables in access

Tags: ms-access

Hi All I've maid 4 queries:

- Query1: contains PlayerName and AvgGamesWon
- Query2: contains PlayerName and AvgGamesLost
- Query3: contains PlayerName and AvgOwnOdds
- Query4: contains PlayerName and AvgOppOdds

PlayerName I've got from an other query that retrieves PlayerName from my GamesTable.

Now I want a table with PlayerName , AvgGamesWon,AvgGamesLost,AvgOwnOdds and AvgOppOdds. But If I tried this I get a lot of double values...

Any idea how I can get around this and what the solution is for this query in access?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure, that your Players query returns only unique records (`Unique Values=Yes` on query properties). Then the query like on picture should work fine.

[image: This query works fine]

Comment: I still get some doubles.

Comment: Check other queries, they should not have repeating PlayerName. Use aggregate functions and group by PlayerName